# Results in databricks on AWS are not displayed when run as a job

Tags: databricks, aws-databricks

Instead of the expected output from a `display(my_dataframe)`, I get `Failed to fetch the result. Retry` when looking at the completed run (also marked as success).

The notebook runs fine, including the expected outputs, when run as an on-demand notebook (same cluster config etc.). It seems to be a UI issue? I honestly don't even know where to look for possible causes.

Comment: Can you try using show() instead of display()?  For me, display() seems to be a databricks notebook function enabling some more notebook visualization features.

Comment: Try to use take() or show() to see if output is visible.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem while running a job on Azure Databricks and restarting my computer (or maybe the explorer..) helped.

Comment: Restarting the browser resolved the issue.